# Voice Recognition Program Error and Command Execution Issue

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, bing-api, openai-whisper

I'm currently working on developing a program using Python that listens to my voice and performs the commands I give. However, I'm encountering a couple of issues that I need help with.

[My repo](https://github.com/Pharaoh-C/Voice-Control-Assistant)

1. Error when increasing/decreasing volume:
   Whenever I try to instruct the program to increase the volume, it throws an error. I'm using a specific function or library for this task, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Could someone assist me in identifying the cause of this error and provide suggestions for a solution?
   Volume up!
   Error transcribing audio: (-2147024809, 'wrong parameter.', (None, None, None, 0, None))
2. Command execution after wake word:
   After uttering the wake word, the program successfully recognizes it and sends the subsequent commands to BingAI for processing. However, instead of executing the commands locally, the program is forwarding them to BingAI. I intended for the program to execute the commands directly. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and suggest possible modifications to achieve the desired behavior?

Any guidance, insights, or code examples that can help me address these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance